# After Windows 8.1 update, I can't boot into ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Whenever I start my computer, it boots directly to Windows 8.1 without giving me an option to boot into ubuntu. Grub was working fine, but after a minor update to Windows, now it doesn't even show up at boot. I've tried to boot Ubuntu again from a USB, but it still loads Windows. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: This should be a very easy fix. Just enter your BIOS/EFI settings and change your boot order so Ubuntu is at the very top. If you don't see Ubuntu as an option, put your hard drive (not Windows Boot Manager) at the top instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)?

There is a free version (Google is your friend)

By the way, you should install Grub on your Linux partition and not on your disk.

Comment: Grub2 does not recommend instlling to a partition as it does not fit. It has to convert to blocklists or hard coded addresses. Any update that moves grub files on drive will require you to reinstall grub. EasyBCD uses an old grub4dos to chain load to grub in a partition. Some have used it with BIOS, but with UEFI it just adds complications. So if a UEFI system do not use EasyBCD.